# How much information is necessary to recreate a survival curve?

Tags: r, survival

Is it possible, using the given information provided in a survival curve figure, to recreate the curve? If not, what additional information would be required?

[image: curve]

I assume if I was to try to recreate this graph, I only have population numbers at each yearly interval, so my graph would appear as a series of steps and flat lines rather than a slowly meandering line. Could I randomize censor dates to re-approximate the curve between yearly intervals?

I am using R.

Comment: There are many tools available online that describe themselves as graph digitizers.  Apparently there is an R package called `digitize` (though I have no idea how, or indeed whether, it works)

Answer (score 0):

The survival curves are clearly presented, so the suggestion from @Henry to digitize them seems most direct. That will give you the 2 survival curves as the authors provided them.

The population numbers at the bottom of the plot don't really help. They are typically the numbers still at risk at the indicated time points, here at the start of each year. The differences in numbers between years come from both events and censoring between the years--both ways that individuals can leave the risk set. In principle you can use the magnitudes of the survival drops at event times along with the numbers at risk to distinguish the numbers of intervening events from the numbers of intervening censorings, but that still would require digitizing the original survival curves to get good estimate of the magnitudes of the drops in the curves.

So just digitize the survival curves.